# different result between Keras predict and Opencv DNN module

Tags: python, opencv, keras, deep-learning

I get different results with this two snippets and cannot figure out why. I tried changing interpolation method on image loading for the keras version, without any luck (this should be correct because OpenCV uses bilinear to resize by default). The model used is the same, but has been converted to caffe because OpenCV DNN don't support H5 weights, conversion has been made with this [tool](https://github.com/microsoft/MMdnn). Results seem to good in both cases (predicted class, is a classification problem), but values are very different (i.e. 0.92 Keras vs 0.66 OpenCV for the top class in an image). Any idea ?

*Keras version*:

```
import argparse
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import model_from_json


def load_image(img_path, show=False):

    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(80, 80), interpolation='bilinear')
    img_tensor = image.img_to_array(img)                    
    img_tensor = np.expand_dims(img_tensor, axis=0)        
    img_tensor /= 255.

    return img_tensor


def predict(image):

    # load model
    with open('model.json', 'r') as json_file:
        model = model_from_json(json_file.read())
    model.load_weights('weights20-0.92.h5')
    new_image = load_image(image, True)

    pred = model.predict(new_image)

    print(pred)


def main():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter, description="")
    p.add_argument('-image', dest='image', action='store', help='image to predict')

    args = p.parse_args()
    predict(args.image)
```

*OpenCV version*

```
import argparse
import cv2
import numpy as np


def predict(image):

    image32 = cv2.imread(image)
    new_image = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image32, scalefactor=(1.0/255.0), size=(80, 80), swapRB=True, crop=False)

    model = cv2.dnn.readNet('net.prototxt', 'net.caffemodel')

    model.setInput(new_image)
    pred = model.forward()

    print(pred)


p = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter, description="")
p.add_argument('-image', dest='image', action='store', help='image to predict')

args = p.parse_args()
predict(args.image)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that key point stands in the resize function, as described [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-read-and-resize-with-opencv-tensorflow-and-pil-3e0f29b992be) Pillow (Keras image is just a wrapper for that) behaves differently than OpenCV, hence the different result. Answer is .. never mix different image processing library if it's not necessary.. :)